# cin doesn't function properly while reading math operations

Tags: c++

I tried to write a function that chop an expression into tokens as below.

```
while(true)
{
    cin >> d_tmp;               
    if(!cin){
        cin.clear();
        cin >> ch_tmp;

        cout << ch_tmp << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << d_tmp << endl;
    }
}
```

However, the function didn't work as I expected. It worked fine when I entered a sequence of random number and character When I typed in "a 3 b" returns 'a' '3' and 'b', but when I typed "3 + 4", all that return are '3' and '4'.

I've tried several testcases with the following code. It seems that if I want the program to print '3' '+' '4', I have to type in "3 ++ 4". This totally confuses me. Anyone have any idea on this??? Thanks!

Comment: What are `d_tmp` and `ch_tmp`?

Comment: It seems as if "+ 4" is interpreted as the number 4 with sign explicitly spelled out.

Comment: d_tmp is an int, ch_tmp is a char.

Comment: @Angew I've tried "3 - 4", and the program prints only "3" and "4". If it's the case you mentioned, "3" and "-4" should be printed instead. Soooo confusing. hahaha

Comment: The `+` or `-` won't be left on the input stream, the error occurs on the space character after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that the types of the variables are:

```
int d_tmp;
char ch_tmp;
```

With the input `3 + 4`, the execution goes as follows:

- `cin >> d_tmp;` reads 3, reads space, stops
- `if(!cin)` is false, goes to else, and prints `3`
- `cin >> d_tmp;` reads `+`, reads space, errors
- `if(!cin)` is true
- `cin >> ch_tmp;` reads `4`

The number parser of the input stream treats `+12` as a number, so it will consume a `+` if it sees it.

Comment: doesn't cin leave the values on the input stream untouched if it fails to read? Correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: @DomePongmongkol: I already explained why it consumed it in the last sentence. It thinks it is reading a number when it sees the `+`. Sees the space, finds out it is wrong. It doesn't put back a char it has consumed.

Comment: I think i get the picture. So '+' is already consumed as a part of an int. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "+" character is eaten by `cin >> d_tmp;` when it tries to parse it as `int` and sets the fail flag